# position of twitter button in twitter-bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is the main page of my blog http://www.lowcoupling.com
it is a tumblr blog based on twitter bootstrap
as you can see I have just placed the twitter button in the right side of the nav bar just after the google plus button.
I can't see why, when the button is loaded related script, it is placed at the top of the bar and not at the same height of the plus button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some styles applied by bootstrap on nav>a elements. The resulting google+ label is inside a link tag. The other one is not. One quick solution is to include the script of the second label (twitter) inside a link tag.

```
<li><a>  <---

<a href="https://twitter.com/lowcoupling" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @lowcoupling</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

</a></li>  <----
```

**UPDATE**
The scripts doesn't consider the link tag as a container so the above won't work. A hack that would work is to give your li tag, `<li style="padding: 14px 15px;"></li>` . But the best you could do is to check the nav>a styles in bootstrap css and copy those on a class of your own, which you will give it to a container of the iframe.

Comment: Yes, it appends the iframe after the link tag. Let me check it a little more.

Comment: This now by default blocked in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this annoying issue also. I fixed it by giving my anchor an ID and then using jQuery to move the Twitter rendered stuff into my anchor:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- Note the ID I put on the link -->
    <li><a href="#" id="twitter-fix">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Whatever" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @Whatever</a>
        <script>
            !function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https'; if (!d.getElementById(id)) { js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); } }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
            // Custom fix here
            $(".nav .twitter-follow-button").detach().appendTo("#twitter-fix");
        </script>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simpler - add a line above the twitter button, and set the height using font-size. This was the code in my style.css:

```
#twitter-fix {
  font-size: 7px;
}
```

And this was inside my navbar (note the br tag):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li id="twitter-fix"><br>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/UserName" class="twitter-follow-button"
  data-size="large" data-show-count="false">Follow @UserName</a>
  <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </li>
</ul>
```